# AWS DynamoDB delete Item using lambda nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to delete some entries from DynamoDB table, but I keep getting the error: ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema

Screen shot of the entry I want to delete, partition key is `identifier`:

[image]

I have tried the following code:

[image]

I am using dynamodb = AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient

what am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete an item, you have to specify the *entire* primary key. In the case of a table with a composite key, that means both partition and sort keys are required.

From documentation for [`DeleteItem` - `Key` attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html):

> For the primary key, you must provide all of the attributes. For example, with a simple primary key, you only need to provide a value for the partition key. For a composite primary key, you must provide values for both the partition key and the sort key.